# Can someone explain how the cartesian equation is formed?

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain how the cartesian equation of $r = 1 - \cos (\theta)$  is $x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2 + 2x^3 + 2xy^2 - y^ 2 = 0$ ?

Comment: Hint: $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\cos \theta=???$ (express the latter also in terms of $x,y$ and then substitute.

Comment: $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, multiplying everything by the root gives $x^2+y^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x$, or $x^2+y^2-x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Square and you should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment was pseudo-copied to an answer (i.e. an answer identical to my comment was posted) I thought I'd just post a full solution completing that comment.

1. Remember:

   $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
   r\cos\theta=x \\
   r\sin\theta=y \\
   r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
   \theta=\arctan\frac{y}{x}\text{ well, in some cases}
   \end{array}\right.;$$
2. Multiply by $r$ to get $r^2=r-r\cos\theta$;
3. Substitute the above equations to get $x^2+y^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x$;
4. Carry $x$ over to the LHS and square to get $x^2+y^2=(x^2+y^2+x)^2$;
5. Expand the square on the right and get $x^4+y^4+x^2+2x^2y^2+2xy^2+2x^3=x^2+y^2$;
6. $x^2$'s cancel out, $y^2$ goes to the left side, and we get:

   $$x^4+y^4+2x^3-y^2+2x^2y^2+2xy^2=0.$$

   Which is precisely what we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

$r^2=r-x\implies x^2+y^2+x=(x^2+y^2)^{\frac12}$. Then square both sides and arrange.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly tricky. Multiply through by $r$ and put $r\cos\theta=x$, that gives $r^2=r-x$ or $x=r-r^2$. Squaring and rearranging gives $2r^3=r^4+y^2$. Squaring again gives $4r^6=r^8+2y^2r^4+y^4$. Substituting $r^2=x^2+y^2$ gives a degree 8 polynomial which factors: $(x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2+2x^3+2xy^2-y^2)(x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2-2x^3-2xy^2-y^2)=0$.

So the first question is whether the second factor is valid or whether it is an artefact of all that squaring. Try putting $y=0,x=2$. That fails to satisfy the first factor, but does satisfy the second. It also fails to satisfy the original equation (whereas $y=0,x=-2$ satisfies the first factor and the original equation but not the second factor).

Since the original equation obviously generates a continuous curve, we conclude that we have $x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2+2x^3+2xy^2-y^2=0$ as required.

Comment: One way to avoid double squaring is to get the form $r=r^2+x$ before squaring and substituting right after, that is, getting $x^2+y^2=(x^2+y^2+x)^2$.

Comment: @MickG Good point! I squared the wrong thing. I should have squared $r$ not $x$! In fact a monument to stupidity followed by perseverance!

Answer (score 0):

$$ r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} , \, \cos \theta = \frac {x} { \sqrt{x^2+y^2}  }$$

Plug them in, squaring it at least twice to get rid of radicals.